# [Solved]Sometimes lightdm crash and restart with no indication

Tags: greeter, desktop, crash

Recently when I work with my laptop installed with elementary os，there's no indication the desktop crashed and lightdm restarted. This situation happens several times within days and let me worry about my unfinished work without saving.
I don't know how, where to start checking this problem. I collect some journal logs but too long for this body. How can I provide for you？

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: elementary
Description:    elementary OS 5.1.3 Hera
Release:    5.1.3
Codename:   hera
```

Edit: I paste some key logs, hope it helps

```
-- Logs begin at Wed 2020-02-12 04:16:11 CST, end at Thu 2020-04-09 08:56:23 CST. --
Apr 08 14:13:50 aart-ThinkPad-X1 StartPreload.sh[994]: /usr/local/gopreload/bin/StartPreload.sh: line 86: 16355 Terminated              $INSTALLDIR/bin/fmlock.gopreload /tmp/preloadlist.txt 2> /dev/null > /dev/null
Apr 08 14:14:08 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gsd-housekeepin[31044]: Failed to enumerate children of /var/tmp/systemd-private-aaccc7ce87bc47a9bc9f2baf19320358-rtkit-daemon.service-aD1h59: Error opening directory '/var/tmp/systemd-private-aaccc7ce87bc47a9bc9f2baf19320358-rtkit-daemon.service-aD1h59': Permission denied
Apr 08 14:14:08 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gsd-housekeepin[31044]: Failed to enumerate children of /var/tmp/systemd-private-aaccc7ce87bc47a9bc9f2baf19320358-chrony.service-M4ZHy9: Error opening directory '/var/tmp/systemd-private-aaccc7ce87bc47a9bc9f2baf19320358-chrony.service-M4ZHy9': Permission denied
Apr 08 14:14:08 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gsd-housekeepin[31044]: Failed to enumerate children of /var/tmp/systemd-private-aaccc7ce87bc47a9bc9f2baf19320358-colord.service-kfXnyL: Error opening directory '/var/tmp/systemd-private-aaccc7ce87bc47a9bc9f2baf19320358-colord.service-kfXnyL': Permission denied
Apr 08 14:14:08 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gsd-housekeepin[31044]: Failed to enumerate children of /tmp/systemd-private-aaccc7ce87bc47a9bc9f2baf19320358-chrony.service-MIWxys: Error opening directory '/tmp/systemd-private-aaccc7ce87bc47a9bc9f2baf19320358-chrony.service-MIWxys': Permission denied
Apr 08 14:14:08 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gsd-housekeepin[31044]: Failed to enumerate children of /tmp/systemd-private-aaccc7ce87bc47a9bc9f2baf19320358-rtkit-daemon.service-PBgkop: Error opening directory '/tmp/systemd-private-aaccc7ce87bc47a9bc9f2baf19320358-rtkit-daemon.service-PBgkop': Permission denied
Apr 08 14:14:08 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gsd-housekeepin[31044]: Failed to enumerate children of /tmp/systemd-private-aaccc7ce87bc47a9bc9f2baf19320358-systemd-resolved.service-E8wmSk: Error opening directory '/tmp/systemd-private-aaccc7ce87bc47a9bc9f2baf19320358-systemd-resolved.service-E8wmSk': Permission denied
Apr 08 14:14:08 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gsd-housekeepin[31044]: Failed to enumerate children of /var/tmp/systemd-private-aaccc7ce87bc47a9bc9f2baf19320358-systemd-resolved.service-iJFAj0: Error opening directory '/var/tmp/systemd-private-aaccc7ce87bc47a9bc9f2baf19320358-systemd-resolved.service-iJFAj0': Permission denied
Apr 08 14:14:08 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gsd-housekeepin[31044]: Failed to enumerate children of /tmp/systemd-private-aaccc7ce87bc47a9bc9f2baf19320358-colord.service-FurOJ4: Error opening directory '/tmp/systemd-private-aaccc7ce87bc47a9bc9f2baf19320358-colord.service-FurOJ4': Permission denied
Apr 08 14:17:01 aart-ThinkPad-X1 CRON[16948]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 08 14:17:01 aart-ThinkPad-X1 CRON[16949]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Apr 08 14:17:01 aart-ThinkPad-X1 CRON[16948]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 08 14:18:50 aart-ThinkPad-X1 StartPreload.sh[994]: /usr/local/gopreload/bin/StartPreload.sh: line 86: 16663 Terminated              $INSTALLDIR/bin/fmlock.gopreload /tmp/preloadlist.txt 2> /dev/null > /dev/null
Apr 08 14:19:03 aart-ThinkPad-X1 fcitx-ui-sogou-qimpanel.desktop[31483]: MainController::SogouImePinYinShow
Apr 08 14:19:03 aart-ThinkPad-X1 fcitx-ui-sogou-qimpanel.desktop[31483]: No systemtrayicon available
Apr 08 14:19:11 aart-ThinkPad-X1 nm-dispatcher[15653]: req:2 'connectivity-change', "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/90restart-dnsmasq.sh": complete: timeout (kill script)
Apr 08 14:19:37 aart-ThinkPad-X1 io.elementary.cerbere.desktop[31178]: [16014:16033:0408/141937.772937:ERROR:socket_stream.cc(218)] Closing stream with result -2
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 kernel: gala[15548]: segfault at 188 ip 00007fd3b1a5fa00 sp 00007ffdadda31d8 error 4 in libmutter-2.so.0.0.0[7fd3b19b6000+159000]
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 kernel: Code: 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 48 8b 47 50 c3 90 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 8b 87 90 00 00 00 c3 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 <f6> 87 88 01 00 00 08 75 07 48 8b 47 38 c3 66 90 48 8b 47 20 48 8b
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gnome-session-binary[30783]: WARNING: Application 'gala.desktop' killed by signal 11
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gnome-session[30783]: gnome-session-binary[30783]: WARNING: Application 'gala.desktop' killed by signal 11
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala.desktop[17631]: Window manager warning: Trying to re-add keybinding "switch-to-workspace-last".
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala.desktop[17631]: Window manager warning: Trying to re-add keybinding "move-to-workspace-last".
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:192: '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' is read-only!
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'OuterStrokeColor' for group 'PlankTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'FillStartColor' for group 'PlankTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'FillEndColor' for group 'PlankTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'InnerStrokeColor' for group 'PlankTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'HorizPadding' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'ItemPadding' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'IndicatorSize' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'IconShadowSize' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'UrgentBounceHeight' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'LaunchBounceHeight' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'FadeOpacity' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'ClickTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'UrgentBounceTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'LaunchBounceTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'ActiveTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'SlideTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'FadeTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'HideTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'GlowSize' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'GlowTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'GlowPulseTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'UrgentHueShift' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'ItemMoveTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'CascadeHide' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'BadgeColor' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:20:45 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[17631]: invalid cast from 'CoglTexture2D' to '(null)'
Apr 08 14:23:50 aart-ThinkPad-X1 StartPreload.sh[994]: /usr/local/gopreload/bin/StartPreload.sh: line 86: 16872 Terminated              $INSTALLDIR/bin/fmlock.gopreload /tmp/preloadlist.txt 2> /dev/null > /dev/null
Apr 08 14:27:27 aart-ThinkPad-X1 fcitx-ui-sogou-qimpanel.desktop[31483]: MainController::SogouImePinYinShow
Apr 08 14:27:27 aart-ThinkPad-X1 fcitx-ui-sogou-qimpanel.desktop[31483]: No systemtrayicon available
Apr 08 14:28:50 aart-ThinkPad-X1 StartPreload.sh[994]: /usr/local/gopreload/bin/StartPreload.sh: line 86: 16998 Terminated              $INSTALLDIR/bin/fmlock.gopreload /tmp/preloadlist.txt 2> /dev/null > /dev/null
Apr 08 14:28:56 aart-ThinkPad-X1 fcitx-ui-sogou-qimpanel.desktop[31483]: MainController::SogouImePinYinShow
Apr 08 14:28:56 aart-ThinkPad-X1 fcitx-ui-sogou-qimpanel.desktop[31483]: No systemtrayicon available
Apr 08 14:29:41 aart-ThinkPad-X1 io.elementary.cerbere.desktop[31178]: [16014:16033:0408/142941.961758:ERROR:socket_stream.cc(218)] Closing stream with result -2
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 kernel: gala[17631]: segfault at 188 ip 00007f114fd1ea00 sp 00007ffd5c502e38 error 4 in libmutter-2.so.0.0.0[7f114fc75000+159000]
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 kernel: Code: 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 48 8b 47 50 c3 90 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 8b 87 90 00 00 00 c3 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 <f6> 87 88 01 00 00 08 75 07 48 8b 47 38 c3 66 90 48 8b 47 20 48 8b
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gnome-session[30783]: gnome-session-binary[30783]: WARNING: Application 'gala.desktop' killed by signal 11
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gnome-session-binary[30783]: WARNING: Application 'gala.desktop' killed by signal 11
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala.desktop[19305]: Window manager warning: Trying to re-add keybinding "switch-to-workspace-last".
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala.desktop[19305]: Window manager warning: Trying to re-add keybinding "move-to-workspace-last".
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:192: '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' is read-only!
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'OuterStrokeColor' for group 'PlankTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'FillStartColor' for group 'PlankTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'FillEndColor' for group 'PlankTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'InnerStrokeColor' for group 'PlankTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'HorizPadding' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'ItemPadding' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'IndicatorSize' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'IconShadowSize' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'UrgentBounceHeight' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'LaunchBounceHeight' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'FadeOpacity' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'ClickTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'UrgentBounceTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'LaunchBounceTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'ActiveTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'SlideTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'FadeTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'HideTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'GlowSize' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'GlowTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'GlowPulseTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'UrgentHueShift' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'ItemMoveTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'CascadeHide' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: Preferences.vala:378: Missing key 'BadgeColor' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
Apr 08 14:32:54 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gala[19305]: invalid cast from 'CoglTexture2D' to '(null)'
Apr 08 14:32:59 aart-ThinkPad-X1 kernel: gala[19305]: segfault at 188 ip 00007f834aa9ea00 sp 00007ffcfa269008 error 4 in libmutter-2.so.0.0.0[7f834a9f5000+159000]
Apr 08 14:32:59 aart-ThinkPad-X1 kernel: Code: 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 48 8b 47 50 c3 90 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 8b 87 90 00 00 00 c3 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 <f6> 87 88 01 00 00 08 75 07 48 8b 47 38 c3 66 90 48 8b 47 20 48 8b
Apr 08 14:32:59 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gnome-session[30783]: gnome-session-binary[30783]: WARNING: Application 'gala.desktop' killed by signal 11
Apr 08 14:32:59 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gnome-session-binary[30783]: WARNING: Application 'gala.desktop' killed by signal 11
Apr 08 14:32:59 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gnome-session[30783]: gnome-session-binary[30783]: WARNING: App 'gala.desktop' respawning too quickly
Apr 08 14:32:59 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gnome-session-binary[30783]: WARNING: App 'gala.desktop' respawning too quickly
Apr 08 14:32:59 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gnome-session-binary[30783]: Unrecoverable failure in required component gala.desktop
Apr 08 14:32:59 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gnome-session[30783]: gnome-session-binary[30783]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Apr 08 14:32:59 aart-ThinkPad-X1 gnome-session-binary[30783]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Apr 08 14:32:59 aart-ThinkPad-X1 fcitx-ui-sogou-qimpanel.desktop[31483]: ICE default IO error handler doing an exit(), pid = 31486, errno = 11
Apr 08 14:32:59 aart-ThinkPad-X1 lightdm[5041]: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session closed for user aart
Apr 08 14:32:59 aart-ThinkPad-X1 kernel: rfkill: input handler enabled
Apr 08 14:32:59 aart-ThinkPad-X1 bluetoothd[1109]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.63 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Apr 08 14:32:59 aart-ThinkPad-X1 bluetoothd[1109]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.63 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
```

Edit: Well, I opened this issue (#766) of gala on github above one weeks ago, they have patched source code already. Now you can receive updates for gala fixed this issue.

Comment: I have the same issue and it happens randomly when I'm switching between workspaces. I tried to do a new installation and isolate some applications, but the problem continues. This problem started when I reinstalled elementary OS and it happens using intel graphics or nvidia with proprietary driver. We have the same errors in the logs.

Comment: I've been experiencing the same problem. (Is it lightdm which is crashing? Looks like libmutter has issues) Where should I report this issue? When switching workspaces (cmd+left/right) sometimes this crash occurs. I'm using an external screen and *something* crashes which forces me to *reduplicate* the screen. I have the following `dmesg` output. [14145.141160] gala[2123]: segfault at 188 ip 00007f4cf7503a00 sp 00007ffdb3795aa8 error 4 in libmutter-2.so.0.0.0[7f4cf745a000+159000] [14145.141170] Code: 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 48 8b 47 50 c3 90 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 8b 87 90 00 00 0

Comment: Same issue for me too. It happens also when I'm making Skype calls

Comment: Yo tengo el mismo problema, sucede cuando cambio de área de trabajo mediante los atajos de teclado.

Comment: A patch for this was accepted and merged today. Hopefully we'll see the fixed package in the updates soon. Here is the relevant issue: https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/766